# Internet Explorer 11 (IE 11) Throws Syntax Error using parseFromString in DOMParser

Tags: javascript, windows, dom, internet-explorer-11

I have some Javascript on a webpage which works fine in Chrome and Firefox; when testing in IE 11 however it fails. I viewed the problem in IE 11 with the debug tools (F12) and the following code was at fault; specifically when using parseFromString a 'Syntax Error' is thrown:

```
if (window.DOMParser)
{                            
    parser =  new DOMParser();
    tmp = parser.parseFromString(resp, "text/xml");
}
```

Any way I can work around this?

Comment: What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: The posted code should work fine in IE11 ?

Comment: @adeneo maybe "parser" is otherwise undeclared. Without the error message itself, it's hard to say. (I wish I knew why it's not completely obvious that error messages should always be included in questions like this.)

Comment: Ok, I've updated this post as I realized I didn't have the full problem stated correctly; and I miss identified the actual error. My apologies.

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error from the parser, it means you've got a syntax error in the text that you're parsing.

Comment: Do you mean setting: var parser?

Comment: No, whatever you put into the parser does not have the correct syntax, so the parser is working, it's telling you that your syntax is off.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For IE this works for me

```
xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async=false;
xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
```

source: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp