# Error thrown with Microsoft.XMLDOM XML Parser in Edge with XML string content

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, microsoft-edge, xmldom

I'm getting the following error with the Microsoft.XMLDOM XML parser in Microsoft EDGE:

`Script(1,1)`

Sometimes it says `start tag does not match end tag`. And other times it gives another error. I wish I could provide the actual error messages but I'm away from a Windows machine and this is what I remember from memory.

The exact same XML content works in Firefox and other browsers. Can anyone see what is going on? This could be an easy fix but again I don't have a Windows computer.

Here is my XML:

```
<s:RichText x="118" visible="true" y="238" text="Text" fontSize="58.73271028037384">
    <s:filters>
        <BorderStrokeFilter alpha="1" angle="45" blurX="3" blurY="3" color="#FFFFFF" distance="0" hideObject="false" inner="false" knockout="false" multiplier="6" quality="3" strength="30" weight="3" xmlns="library://ns.flexcapacitor.com/flex"/>
        <BorderStrokeFilter alpha="1" angle="45" blurX="3" blurY="3" color="#000000" distance="0" hideObject="false" inner="false" knockout="false" multiplier="6" quality="3" strength="30" weight="3" xmlns="library://ns.flexcapacitor.com/flex"/>
    </s:filters>
    <s:textFlow>
        <s:TextFlow whiteSpaceCollapse="preserve" version="3.0.0" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"><s:p><s:span s:fontWeight="bold">Here is some text</s:span></s:p></s:TextFlow>
    </s:textFlow>
</s:RichText>
```

Here is my validation method:

```
function validateXML(txt) {

    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);

        if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
            txt = "Error Code: " + xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode + "\\n";
            txt = txt + "Error Reason: " + xmlDoc.parseError.reason;
            txt = txt + "Error Line: " + xmlDoc.parseError.line;
            return txt;
        }
        else {
            return "No errors found";
        }
    }
    // Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation.createDocument) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");

        if (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror").length > 0) {
            return xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror")[0];
        }
        else {
            return "No errors found";
        }
    }
    else {
        return "Your browser does not support XML validation";
    }
}


var xml = '<s:RichText x="118"></s:RichText>';
var result = validateXML(xml);
```

Can someone with Windows 10 run this? I've created a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvoLYq).

Comment: Your codepen fails for me in all of IE11, Edge, Firefox and Chrome on Windows 10, but that's not because of Windows 10.  It's because you haven't declared the URL to bind the namespace prefix `s` to.  I would also expect the larger XML document above to fail to parse for much the same reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in my other code that was causing the error I was encountering but I also found out that when there's an error in Edge or IE they will log an error in the console.

Also, starting around IE 10 or 11 DOMParser is supported. The solution is to switch the if statement conditions to check for Domparser

if (window.DOMParser || document.implementation.createDocument)

and then put a try catch block around the parse method.

Although, it doesn't look like IE gives a line or column error information. I haven't been able to extensively test it.

The updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvoLYq) can be tested:

```
function validateXML(txt) {


    // Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, newer IE and Edge, etc.
    if (document.implementation.createDocument) {
        console.log("Before creating domparser");
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        try {
            var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        };

        console.log("After DomParser instance. Errors: "+ xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror").length);
        if (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror").length > 0) {
            return xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror")[0];
        }
        else {
            return "No errors found";
        }
    }
    // code for older IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);

        if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
            txt = "Error Code: " + xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode + "\\n";
            txt = txt + "Error Reason: " + xmlDoc.parseError.reason;
            txt = txt + "Error Line: " + xmlDoc.parseError.line;
            console.log("I work in Windows IE");
            return txt;
        }
        else {
            return "No errors found";
        }
    }
    else {
        return "Your browser does not support XML validation";
    }
}


var xml = '<s:RichText x="118" xmlns:s="f">test</f/></s:RichText>';
var result = validateXML(xml);
console.log(result); 
if (typeof result == "string") {
  document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>"+result+"</pre>";
}
else {
  document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>"+result.outerHTML+"</pre>";
}
```